# Webpack: load background images in scss file not showing

Tags: angular, webpack, sass-loader

I try to use webpack [sass-loader](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader) to load a `.scss` file which contains background images. Part of the `.scss` is like

```
.clouds_two {
  background: url(require("../../../images/cloud_two.png"));   //no error, just not display
  //background: url("../../../images/cloud_two.png");     // 404 error
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300%;
  -webkit-animation: cloud_two 75s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: cloud_two 75s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: cloud_two 75s linear infinite;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}
```

Corresponding loaders in my webpack config file are set as

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] // sass-loader not scss-loader
  },
  {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
  }, // inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
```

My `.scss` file is in `src/app/components/login/` and the image is in `src/images/`. The webpack output folder is `dist` which is of same level as `src` folder.

The problem is when I use `background: url(require("../../../images/cloud_two.png"));`, there's no error but the background image not showing.

If I use `background: url("../../../images/cloud_two.png");`, there's a 404 error complaining `http://localhost:8080/images/cloud_two.png`.

The [sass-loader](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader)'s readme has a `Problems with url(...)` section, but it can't fix my case.

Comment: The url used should be relative to the sass file.  If you inspect the network tab does it actually download the image?

Comment: @cgatian Yeah, I use relative url to access the `.png` file. The browser tries to download the file but gets a 404.

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out. In this [webpack.common.js](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js) file, the `CopyWebpackPlugin` can copy files and directories into webpack.

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
  from: 'src/assets',
  to: 'assets'
}]),
```

The path didn't match my project structure. And after I change it, my `.png`s can be copied to webpack. And in my `.scss` file, `background: url("assets/cloud_two.png");` works for me.

Note: the path in `url()` is relative to the webpack output folder. Eg. my output folder is like

```
dist
    /assets
        cloud_two.png
    main.bundle.js
    vendor.bundle.js
    polypill.bundle.js
```